# Get option value and append to search as additional keyword?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I have selection fields and a search box. I want users to select a recipe, then search ingredients by keyword in the search box. The search result domain should look like: https://www.domain.com?s=RECIPE+KEYWORD

The code I created below doesn't seem to append the RECIPE value though, only the keyword.

```
<select id="recipe-select" class="form-style" name="recipeType">
    <option selected disabled>Select Your Recipe</option>
    <option value="Cakes" name="selectedRecipe">I want to make Cakes</option>
    <option value="Pies" name="selectedRecipe">I want to make Pies</option>
</select>
<div class="widget box" id="search-box">
    <div class="widget-search">
        <form action=" https://www.domain.com" method="post" onSubmit="search();return false;">
            <input name="s" class="form-style" type="text" placeholder="Search" id="searchbox">
            <button><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>    

<script type="text/javascript">
    function search() {
        alert("View all results?");
        var a = document.getElementById("searchbox").value;
        a = "https://www.domain.com/?s=<?php echo $_POST['selectedRecipe']; ?>+" + a;
        a = a.replace(" ","+");
        alert(a);
        document.location = a;
    }
</script>
```

I want the result of the search URL to look like this: https://www.domain.com?s=Cakes+keyword

Where the option value is automatically appended as a search keyword. The below doesn't seem to work.

```
<?php echo $_POST['selectedRecipe']; ?>
```

**Thank you everyone for your input! Resolved! :)**

Comment: If you send data through the URL you need to use `$_GET` to retrieve it. Also the parameter is named `s`, not `selectedRecipe`

Comment: `$_POST['selectedRecipe']` is the recipe they selected when the submitted the form the previous time, not the current selection. Is that what you really want?

Comment: Hi, I changed both to '<?php echo $_GET['s']; ?>' but it still doesn't append.

Comment: @Barmar, possibly yes. The thing is, the search box is originally hidden until a selection is made (they don't hit submit though, just select the recipe).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add recipe and keywords like this in your search function...

```
var keyword = document.getElementById("searchbox").value;
var recipe = document.getElementById("recipe-select").value;
a = "https://www.example.com/?s=" + recipe + ' ' + keyword;
```

Code should look something like this...
http://codepen.io/shramee/pen/xEvrWZ

Hope that helps ;)

Comment: This works! Only thing is though... it doesn't actually go to the results page?? Any help? :)

Comment: Replacing `https://www.example.com/` with your domain might help... Lemme know ;)

Comment: Sorry, yes. I did replace the domain. The page just stays on the current page rather than redirecting to mydomain.com?s=cakes+keyword

Comment: Ohh... Remove `return;` after `alert(a);`

Comment: Ah! I figured it!! It was the alert(a); return; bit. I removed return; ...Thanks sooo much! I will save your other fix as a backup too :)

Comment: In case you are using code from codepen... I returned the function after it to avoid redirection...

Comment: Haha, yes! Just figured too :)

Answer (score 1):

You should be getting the recipe type in Javascript, not PHP, because PHP doesn't run until you submit the form. Also, the recipe select box isn't in the form, and it doesn't have `name="selectedRecipe"` (that name is on the `<option>`s, but that doesn't do anything).

```
function search() {
    alert("View all results?");
    var recipeType = document.getElementById("recipe-select").value;
    var keyword = document.getElementById("searchbox").value;
    a = "https://www.domain.com/?s=" + encodeURIComponent(recipeType) + " " + encodeURIComponent(keyword);
    a = a.replace(" ","+");
    alert(a);
    document.location = a;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Don't use php $_POST because you need to send the values not get them. $_POST will be empty.

```
    <select id="recipe-select" class="form-style" name="recipeType">
        <option selected disabled>Select Your Recipe</option>
        <option value="Cakes" name="selectedRecipe">I want to make Cakes</option>
        <option value="Pies" name="selectedRecipe">I want to make Pies</option>
    </select>
    <div class="widget box" id="search-box">
        <div class="widget-search">
            <form action=" https://www.domain.com" method="post" id="exampleForm" onSubmit="search();return false;">
                <input name="s" class="form-style" type="text" placeholder="Search" id="searchbox">
                <button><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>    

    <script type="text/javascript">
     document.getElementById('exampleForm').addEventListener('submit', function(evt){
            evt.preventDefault();
            var a = document.getElementById("searchbox").value;
            a = "https://www.domain.com/?s="+encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('recipe-select').value)+ "+" + a;
            alert(a);
            document.location.href = a;
     });
    </script>
```